# PySpark: how to merge two dataframes with one shared column but different number of rows

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 pyspark dataframes, one has 2 columns (df1: id, code), the other one (df2) has more columns but has the same column - code.  There are different number of rows, but all the values in column Code in df2 has one matching row in Code in df1.

Sample df1:

| id | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | code1 |
| 2 | code2 |
| 3 | code3 |
| 4 | code4 |

Sample df2:

| code | column 2 |
| --- | --- |
| code1 | stuff1 |
| code1 | stuff2 |
| code1 | stuff3 |
| code2 | stuff4 |
| code2 | ... |
| code3 | ... |
| code3 | ... |

Desired output:

| code | column 2 | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | stuff1 | 1 |
| code1 | stuff2 | 1 |
| code1 | stuff3 | 1 |
| code2 | stuff4 | 2 |
| code2 | ... | 2 |
| code3 | ... | 3 |
| code3 | ... | 3 |

I've tried using 'join', but I keep getting extra rows with null values. Any clue how to achieve this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: have you tried joins ? can you post what you have tried so far ?